# Issue with passing too many arguments to lower level functions

Tags: java, oop

I am struggling to how to improve the code of the problem that I written below.

I have a folder with subfolders containing many xml files
Each file represents an single object

- Parent Folder

  - Attributes

    - id1.xml
    - id2.xml
    - id3.xml
  - AttributeGroups

    - id4.xml
    - id5.xml
    - id6.xml
  - UserTypes

    - id7.xml
    - id8.xml

Each xml contains references to other objects.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductInformation>
   <AttributeList>
        <Attribute ID="id1">
            <AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="id4"></AttributeGroupLink>
            <UserTypeLink UserTypeID="id8"></UserTypeLink>
            <UserTypeLink UserTypeID="id9"></UserTypeLink>
        </Attribute>
    </AttributeList>
</ProductInformation>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductInformation>
   <AttributeList>
        <Attribute ID="id2">
            <AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="id5"></AttributeGroupLink>
            <AttributeGroupLink AttributeGroupID="id6"></AttributeGroupLink>
            <UserTypeLink UserTypeID="id7"></UserTypeLink>
            <UserTypeLink UserTypeID="id9"></UserTypeLink>
        </Attribute>
    </AttributeList>
</ProductInformation>
```

I want to write a program to loop through each xml file, read the relevant attributes to get the referenced ids. If a file with the referenced id does not exist, I want to log that.

I have written a first pass that works. However I think that the design can be improved, as I am

- Passing a lot of data from higher level functions to lower level functions
- Unable to log all the information I want such as

  - Directory Name where the error was found
- Unsure how to only log each unique error once (i.e. above id9

My code

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fullPath = "[Path to Folder]";
        fullPath = fullPath.replace("\\", "/");
        Path dir = Paths.get(fullPath);
        readDirectory(dir);
    }

    public static void readDirectory(Path dir) throws IOException {


        List<String> xmlList = createListOfAllXMLFiles(dir);

        Files.walk(dir).forEach(
                //path -> showFile(path.toFile())
                path -> {
                    try {
                        if (path.toFile().isFile()) {
                            readXML(path, xmlList );
                        }
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public static List<String> createListOfAllXMLFiles(Path dir) {
        List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try (Stream<Path> walkStream = Files.walk(dir)) {
            walkStream.filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile()).forEach(f -> {
                String fileName = f.getFileName().toString().substring(0, f.getFileName().toString().lastIndexOf('.'));

                fileList.add(fileName );
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fileList;
    }

    public static void readXML(Path path, List<String> fileList) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        Document document;
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        try {
            document = docBuilder.parse(path.toFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        readContents(document.getDocumentElement(), fileList);

    }

    public static void readContents(Node node, List<String> fileList) {
        // do something with the current node instead of System.out
        //System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

        checkAttributes(node, fileList);


        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                //calls this method for all the children which is Element
                readContents(currentNode, fileList);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void checkAttributes(Node element, List<String> fileList) {
        String lookupString = "ID";

        String nodeName = element.getNodeName();
        NamedNodeMap attributes = element.getAttributes();
        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = attributes.item(i);
            String attributeName = node.getNodeName();
            String attributeValue = node.getNodeValue();

            if (attributeName.contains(lookupString)) {

                boolean idExists = fileList.contains(attributeValue);

                if (!idExists) {
                    System.out.println("  Cannot find attributeName: " + attributeName + "; attributeValue: " + attributeValue + "; nodeName: " + nodeName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can utilize an _[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)_ for the _NodeList_, _//*[@*[contains(name(), 'ID')]]_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reduce the spaghetti, make each method fulfill a small step that returns a result and make each step happen one by one in the main method, passing on each result to the next method.

Here's an example of how that could be done.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fullPath = "[Path to Folder]";
    fullPath = fullPath.replace("\\", "/");
    Path dir = Paths.get(fullPath);
    List<String> xmlFileList = createListOfAllXMLFiles(dir);
    List<Document> xmlDocuments = readDirectory(dir);
    xmlDocuments.forEach(doc -> readContents(doc.getDocumentElement(), xmlFileList));
}

public static List<Document> readDirectory(Path dir) throws IOException {
    List<Document> documents = new LinkedList<>();
    Files.walk(dir).forEach(
            //path -> showFile(path.toFile())
            path -> {
                    if (path.toFile().isFile()) {
                        try {
                            Document document = readXML(path);
                            documents.add(document);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        //System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
            }
    );
    return documents;
}

public static List<String> createListOfAllXMLFiles(Path dir) {
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try (Stream<Path> walkStream = Files.walk(dir)) {
        walkStream.filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile()).forEach(f -> {
            String fileName = f.getFileName().toString().substring(0, f.getFileName().toString().lastIndexOf('.'));

            fileList.add(fileName );
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return fileList;
}

public static Document readXML(Path path) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

    Document document;
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    document = docBuilder.parse(path.toFile());
    return document;
}

public static void readContents(Node node, List<String> fileList) {
    // do something with the current node instead of System.out
    //System.out.println(node.getNodeName());

    checkAttributes(node, fileList);


    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            //calls this method for all the children which is Element
            readContents(currentNode, fileList);
        }
    }
}

public static void checkAttributes(Node element, List<String> fileList) {
    String lookupString = "ID";

    String nodeName = element.getNodeName();
    NamedNodeMap attributes = element.getAttributes();
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = attributes.item(i);
        String attributeName = node.getNodeName();
        String attributeValue = node.getNodeValue();

        if (attributeName.contains(lookupString)) {

            boolean idExists = fileList.contains(attributeValue);

            if (!idExists) {
                System.out.println("  Cannot find attributeName: " + attributeName + "; attributeValue: " + attributeValue + "; nodeName: " + nodeName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```